# How can I fix the SVN import line endings error?

Tags: svn, import, line-endings

I have to import an huge SVN repository that I have to transfer from one server to another. So I exported it from the old server:

```
svnadmin dump . > archive.svn
```

and imported it on the new one:

```
svnadmin load . < archive.svn
```

In the middle of the import process I got this error:

```
Cannot accept non-LF line endings in 'svn:ignore' property
```

How can I fix this? I have full control of both servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you changed the server version? This is a known issue in 1.6, and causes problems when going from 1.4 or 1.5.

Subversion 1.6 no longer accepts carriage returns (^M) in property files. You'll need to fix the line breaks in your svn:ignore file(s), or recreate if that's easier.

Alternatively, you could go for [Subversion 1.7](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download), or use [uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/).

Comment: I updated the old server to the latest version, but I still got the same issue.

Comment: What were you using before? Have you tried setting the file properties to ensure that the correct format is used? There's a good post [here](https://mikewest.org/2006/06/working-with-subversion-file-properties) that explains how...

Comment: I ended up ignoring the line endings with a paramter passed to svnadmin load

Comment: Please post what parameter you used to ignore line endings.

Answer (score 14):

You have 2 options, repair the source or disable prop validation.

**Repairing the source *(svn:log and svn:ignore)*:**

```
sed -e '/^svn:log$/,/^K / s/^M/ /' -e '/^svn:ignore$/,/^PROPS-END$/ s/^M/\n/' archive.svn > repaired-archive.svn

svnadmin load . < repaired-archive.svn
```

Where **^M** is a control character, that means 0D in hex. To get it use ^V^M (**control V control M**) instead ^M (circumflex M or control M)

**Disabling prop validation:**

```
svnadmin load --bypass-prop-validation . < archive.svn
```

Comment: Be careful that the sed command above gives me this error `svnadmin: E200014: Checksum mismatch for` when loading a binary file. @tangens sed works for me.

Comment: I just successfully repaired a dump file, see answer below

Answer (score 7):

The first option of the answer of @ventura10 sounded good but **didn't work** for me. The `sed` command changed some versioned content outside the properties section resulting in md5 mismatches while loading the dump.

Because my repository has no properties with binary content I changed the sed command to correct all properties and not only `svn:log` and `svn:ignore`. I was also sure that no versioned file contained a line starting with `Prop-content-length:`. Otherwise I would have got an error when loading the dump.

```
sed -e '/^Prop-content-length: /,/^PROPS-END$/ s/^M/ /' svn.dump > svn.dump.repaired
```

It's important to replace `^M` with  `[blank]`, because the size of the property value must not change.

**The note of @ventura10 is still valid:**

> ^M is a control character, that means 0D in hex. To get it use ^V^M
>   (control V control M) instead ^M (circumflex M or control M)

It's hard to believe that upgrading an existing repository from svn 1.4 to svn 1.7 makes this step nessecary, but I've found no other way to get rid of the carriage returns that are no longer accepted since svn 1.6.

Comment: You can use the HEX value in the command `sed -e '/^Prop-content-length: /,/^PROPS-END$/ s/\x0D/ /' svn.dump > svn.dump.repaired`

Answer (score 7):

With a little gymnastics you can work around this using `svnsync`, which has the ability to fix the EOLs. Let's say that your repository is dumped in `archive.svn`.

First create the repository to load the repo back, ignoring the EOL problems:

```
svnadmin create repo
svnadmin load repo < archive.svn --bypass-prop-validation
```

Now create a new repository for copying into:

```
svnadmin create repo-fixed
```

`svnsync` requires some pre-commit hook, even if you don't use it, so just use your editor to create an empty one in `repo-fixed/hooks/pre-revprop-change`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 0
```

Initialize the destination repository for `svnsync`:

```
svnsync init file:///path/to/repo-fixed file:///path/to/repo
```

Now copy the entire repository over:

```
svnsync sync file:///path/to/repo-fixed
```

Whew! `svnsync` will even give you good news: `NOTE: Normalized svn:* properties to LF line endings` (Why the Subversion team didn't update `svnadmin` to do the same normalization is a mystery to me.)

Once that's done, dump the new repository:

```
svnadmin dump repo-fixed > archive-fixed.svn
```

**You now have `archive-fixed.svn`, which should be identical to `archive.svn` except the EOLs have been fixed as needed.**

(Optional) You can now remove the temporary repository you used for `svnsync`:

```
rm -rf repo-fixed
```

***Update*** It turns out if you load this new dump, your Subversion client gets an error: `Repository UUID does not match expected UUID`. You'll have to use `svnadmin setuuid ...` to [change the UUID ID to what it used to be](https://serverfault.com/a/248506).

(This post is a culmination of a multitude of snippets and partial solutions I found around the web. Thanks to all the people who knew more than I did; I just put it all together.)

See also:

- [Copying subversion repositories with history using svnsync](http://www.hackvalue.nl/en/article/123/copying_subversion_repositories_with_history_using_svnsync)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28472420/421049
- https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt

Comment: Great work! I found I had to set the execution bit of the hook: chmod u+x gjbh-fixed/hooks/pre-revprop-change

Answer (score 3):

Use [svndumptool](https://github.com/jwiegley/svndumptool):

```
svndumptool.py eolfix-prop svn:ignore svn.dump svn.dump.repaired
```

@tangens solution works too for me, but it's not perfect as I'm getting an extra space character as the replacement of the carriage return characters. I did however test that the svn:ignore still works with that extra space, but I didn't test the other SVN properties.

The downside of using the svndumptool is it can only work on one svn property at one time, which is time consuming if your dump files are big.

---

*Some findings*

You might be curious on why @tangens didn't replace the ^M with empty character. If you try to replace it with empty character, you will be getting this error:

```
svnadmin: E140001: Dumpstream data appears to be malformed
```

The dump file stores `Prop-content-length` property which will be matched against the content of the actual content of the property. Replacing ^M to an empty character will reduce the property content length, hence the error.

svndumptool will change the `Prop-content-length` and `Content-length` respectively.

Comment: I just downloaded and installed svndumptool.py 0.6.1, and the `eolfix-prop` command is nowhere to be found!

Comment: It looks like the command is only added after version 0.6.1. As you can see in [this commit](https://github.com/jwiegley/svndumptool/commit/38673392c1dea29303667fc4ea34726e64d248bf), it was dated at 2013. Even version [0.7.0 commit](https://github.com/jwiegley/svndumptool/commit/b24dfa481a1f10c923904902a1621b551a756191#diff-0c5514081fb7b6c087da4a44ae668f7f) was done at 2009.

Comment: So how do I get these later versions? The latest I could find was 0.6.1.

Comment: @GarretWilson: Just download from github master.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error when upgrading a 1.6 repo to 1.8.  I found a number of "Fixes" on the net.

The *--bypass-prop-validation* did not appeal to me because it postpones the problem, the next time you need to restore the repo you will hit the same promblem.

I found a bash script to loop through the revisions getting the comments and setting them again but this did not work.

An improvement on ventura10's solution did the job.  Because of the size of the dump I ended up using the single command to remove the unwanted characters while restoring the dump

```
    sed -e '/^svn:log$/,/^K / s/^M/ /' -e '/^svn:ignore$/,/^PROPS-END$/ s/^M/\n/' /path/to/svn.dump | svnadmin load /path/to/repo
```

NOTE:

> Where ^M is a control character, that means 0D in hex. To get it use
>   ^V^M (control V control M) instead ^M (circumflex M or control M)

Answer (score 1):

I just repaired a svn dump file successfully. It also had a CRLF in the properties, which caused an Exception in SVN Edge dump import (they have a really bad import routine). Then I "installed" **svnserve** for testing, which was much easier than expected (instructions for Windows OS):

1. download and install TortoiseSVN or another software that includes svn command line tools. I already had it installed
2. start `cmd.exe`, run `svnserve -d`. This cmd window is busy now.
3. start another `cmd.exe`create a repo: `svnadmin create d:\svn_repos\test12`
4. load the dump into the repo: `svnadmin load d:\svn_repos\test12 < d:\temp\svn\backup_test.dump`

svnserve will give you detailed info what failed.

And here's what you have to repair (original on left, repaired on right side):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used `svnadmin load --normalize-props {myrepo} < {mydumpfile}` and it worked perfectly.

The `--normalize-props` switch was added to subversion 1.10. For details, refer to https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.10.html#normalize-props

Reproducing for convenience -

> **New --normalize-props option for svnadmin load**
>
> A new --normalize-props option has been added to the svnadmin load command. This option can be used to automatically repair non-LF line endings in properties such as svn:log or svn:ignore. Such invalid line endings were accepted by older servers and can be found in repository dumps of older repositories, but are rejected by Subversion 1.6 and later.
>
> Calling svnadmin load with --normalize-props will automatically repair all invalid property line endings found in the dumpstream, thus ensuring that the appropriate values are loaded into the repository.

Comment: it does not work, i am on svn version 1.13 and somehow this still fails

Comment: Just for the record: didn't help me either using 1.10.4.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the commentary of the commit was too big.