# Svn non-LF line ending problems with svn:ignore on dump load

Tags: svn, line-endings, svnadmin

I'm trying to use dump files to migrate a repository (with history intact) on a system running svn version 1.2.3 to one running 1.7.1. Since the original repository is such an early version, using `svnrdump` directly is not an option. I used `svnadmin dump` and then moved the (8 GB) dump file to the 1.7.1 system. However, when I use the `svnrdump load` command from there, after 231 revisions, I get the following error

```
svnrdump: E125005: Cannot accept non-LF line endings in 'svn:ignore' property
```

I've tried removing the `svn:ignore` property from revision 231 to no avail, as well as multiple third-party applications like svn2svn (we use authentication, so no dice). and `svndumptool eolfix`/`svndumptool copy` (only works on .txt files, apparently).

Originally I was getting a similar error after 11 revisions on the 'svn:log' revprop which I fixed by running `dos2unix` (broke it even more) and then using a script/manually fixing each file that `svnadmin dump` failed on.

I have admin access to both repos/root access to both systems (unix, not sure what distro). This is an old, currently believed to be unused repository that we want to save just in case some of the projects are needed again. Also, the way the new repositories are laid out using `svnadmin load` is very complicated. Is there an easy fix for the svn:ignore error? Or an easier way to move the whole thing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you compile subversion from sources? It seems there's an easy way to patch "svnrdump load" code to convert CRLF to LFs on the fly in the same manner as it is done for svn:mergeinfo.

Comment: Compiling subversion is certainly possible, but rather difficult. I've been attempting it for whole morning with very little success. Additionally, `svnrdump` in SVN 1.7.5, the version on a different machine I have access to but doesn't house repos, should have the functionality to convert non-LF endings to LF (at least, there are comments in the source code to that effect), but that doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: Yes, subversion compilation a beat complicated if you don't know a secret way: http://vcs.atspace.co.uk/2012/06/29/how-to-build-subversion-on-debian-gnulinux/ I can't reproduce your problem, whatever I do, SVN translates svn:ignore to LFs automatically. But what you could do --- just edit 'set_node_property' function of subversion/svnrdump/load_editor.c to process svn:ignore exactly in the same manner as svn:mergeinfo is processed in this function (I mean 'svn_subst_translate_cstring2' call). I'm sure this should help, though I didn't try because I can't reproduce.

Comment: I appreciate the help, and I agree that it certainly is an odd problem to have. I too was wondering why SVN isn't converting it automatically, it's right there in the source code, but it might have something to do with the old version. I have installed 1.6.x in a different directory and am attempting to see if dumping the files via a newer version will eliminate the cause of the problem rather than fixing it afterward. I also put them into a tarball and might untar on a different machine, dump, and then load. We'll see. Again, thanks for the help, I'll definitely give it a try if I have to.

Comment: I have hit the same problem when trying to load repo with v1.8.10 of `svnadmin`. Actually, the dump was created with the same utility on the same PC – I am just restoring the dump from backup. I personally think this is a bug, because created dump is a way "unusable". Fortunately, utility provides a "fix": use `--bypass-prop-validation` option, that worked for me. But again, cannot this conversion be applied on-the-fly (e.g. via extra `--fix-crlf-prop-value`)? Because now after import I believe dumps will still have that "hidden" problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix the SVN import line endings error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279222/how-can-i-fix-the-svn-import-line-endings-error)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:
`svndumptool eolfix-prop svn:ignore`

instead of: 
`svndumptool eolfix`