# SVN: "Found malformed header [...] in revision file"

Tags: svn, mysql, revision, svnadmin

This is kind of a continuation of the question [Svn non-LF line ending problems with svn:ignore on dump load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638380/svn-non-lf-line-ending-problems-with-svnignore-on-dump-load), but a very different problem.

Backstory: After creating a dump file using `svnadmin`, I was getting this error:

```
svnrdump: E125005: Cannot accept non-LF line endings in 'svn:ignore' property
```

Eventually I found the file that was causing this and removed the `^M` from the end of the lines seen below and adjusted the character count accordingly.

```
PLAIN
K 10 
svn:ignore
V 35
.*^M
classes^M
faces-config.xml.l4t^M

END
ENDREP
```

However, now when I try to dump the repository I get this error:

```
svnadmin: E160004: Found malformed header ' 0.0.r233/2200' in revision file
```

This header is only located in the last few lines of the revision file:

```
other stuff here
END
ENDREP
id: 0.0.r233/2200
type: dir
pred: 0.0.r232/3179
count: 233
text: 233 2082 105 105 8892ed0c073a063ccf02d7ad39463b16
cpath: /
copyroot: 0 /

2u.6.t232-1 modify false true /trunk/other/stuff/here


2200 2339
```

I've tried making some minute changes to the file, but I haven't been able to figure out what this error means. I've tried skipping it various ways, converting it on import, and of course googling the problem but have not been able to come up with anything. I have root access to everything and have made backups, so I'm not worried about breaking anything. Does anyone know what I might do to fix this?