# subversion svn sync message meaning

Tags: svn, svnsync

I've tried to create a mirror repository using svnsync.

Everything is working fine but after the sync process is done it is showing below message.

**NOTE: Normalized svn:* properties to LF line endings (2 rev-props, 0 node-props).**

I've searched about this message and I found nothing(I would say I couldn't understood)

Can anyone explains what does that message means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=315838) claims:

> Subversion has always documented that properties had to have LF line
>   endings. In 1.6 the server started enforcing it.

although I could not find official docs about it.

Above change caused [bug](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3404):

> svnsync fails when source has ^M in svn:* properties (eol-style).

[Bug was fixed](http://marc.info/?l=subversion-commits&m=124304745023834) in svnsync by automatically changing SVN props EOL to LF:

> Fix issue #3404: Normalize line endings in svn:* props during svnsync.
>   Always automatically convert all svn:* properties to LF line ending
>   style, and notify about all normalizations collectively after all else
>   is done.

Comment: That means everything is fine in my case. Isn't it?

Comment: @GangadharJannu Yes, everything is fine, that is expected behavior.